# Rewriterule for CodeIgniter not working

Tags: codeigniter, mod-rewrite, apache2

I have installed a clean Apache2 (plus PHP & MySQL) server and enabled the `mod_rewrite` in the apache config. 
I added the `.htaccess` file to remove the index.php from the url as described in the CodeIgniter wiki.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

I placed this file in the website's root.

When I try to access the url `mydomain.local/index.php/welcome` then I get the default page of CodeIgniter. But when I try to access the same page through `mydomain.local/welcome` then I get the 404 page.

How can I check if the whole rewrite rule is working? And why isn't it working?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the solution. The htaccess file wasn't allowed to run by the Apache config. So I had to set the `AllowOverride` flag on the directory to `AllowOverride ALL`.

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 9):

Assuming that your configuration (**/application/config/config.php**) has the index_page disabled:

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

And your Apache **DocumentRoot** is: **/srv/www/**

Create an **.htaccess** file at the same level as your **/application/** directory, with the following content:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

You should notice that **RewriteBase** points to the **DocumentRoot** (/).
If the **index.php** is in another directory, your should change **RewriteBase** accordingly.

For a directory structure like:

```
/srv/www/application/
/srv/www/system/
/srv/www/index.php
/srv/www/.htaccess
```

Your **RewriteBase** should be: **/**

For a directory structure like:

```
/srv/www/codeigniter/application/
/srv/www/codeigniter/system/
/srv/www/codeigniter/index.php
/srv/www/codeigniter/.htaccess
```

Your **RewriteBase** should be: **/codeigniter/**

And so on, you get the picture.

Answer (score 1):

Default .htaccess (from ci userguide http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html)

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

I have confuse above code for a moment, but i have code like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|.*\.css|.*\.js|.*\.png)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L]
```

On localhost you must add "./" in front of index.php (3rd line) because in my case, ci directory not placed on root. I think **"./"** means it should be **relative** path.
For additional condition `".*\.css|.*\.js|.*\.png"`, it means apache should not rewrite on file with extensions css, js and png.

Answer (score 0):

you need to remove the index.php from the index page in the config file

**/application/config/config.php**

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Try this .htaccess stuff, it's what I'm using:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

You may also need to enable `mod_rewite` in you apache config.

Comment: Not working :( Isn't there a way to check if the whole .htaccess file is being executed?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the uri_protocol config settings. Also, some servers require this modification in the htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/?$1 [L]
```

The question mark after that last slash. Try that.

Also make sure your mod_rewrite is on.

Comment: Mod_rewrite is on and is loaded based on the phpinfo() info. But the addition is not working. I really start wondering if the whole rewrite mod is working...

Comment: Hm, is it rewriting ANYTHING? Do some tests, even outside CI, then you'll be able to localize the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are encountering a `500 Internal Server Error`. The first place to look for is the apache `error.log` file. For me the error was related to the command `AddOutputFilterByType`.

> Invalid command 'AddOutputFilterByType', perhaps misspelled or defined
>   by a module not included in the server configuration.

For my configuration, two modules were not enabled in the apache configuration, while the respective commands were being used in the `.htaccess`. So once I enabled the `filter_module` and the `deflate_module` everything was back to normal.