# Codeigniter URL rewrite to remove index.php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

First of all, i have tried the suggestion specified in here:

- [CodeIgniter removing index.php not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24357271/codeigniter-removing-index-php-not-working)
- [codeignitor: Remove index.php not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20523033/codeignitor-remove-index-php-not-working)
- [CodeIgniter .htaccess index.php rewrite not working on user directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28258126/codeigniter-htaccess-index-php-rewrite-not-working-on-user-directory)
- [How to remove "index.php" in codeigniter's path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445385/how-to-remove-index-php-in-codeigniters-path)
- https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/urls/remove_index.php.html
- [Rewriterule for CodeIgniter not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259425/rewriterule-for-codeigniter-not-working)

I am trying to remove the infamous `index.php` on the address bar.

This is my current configuration:

> In my /etc/apache2/sites-available/my.website.com.conf file i put this:

```
<Directory /path/to/root/directory/>
   AllowOverride All
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
</Directory>
```

In my /etc/apache2/apache2.conf file, i put this:

```
<Directory /path/to/root>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

> In my codeigniter root directory (same dir with index.php), i have a .htaccess like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /

        #Removes access to the system folder by users.
        #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
        #previously this would not have been possible.
        #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

        #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
        #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
        #Submitted by: Fabdrol
        #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

        #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
        #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
        #request to index.php

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</ifmodule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
        # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
        # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
        # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

        ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</ifmodule>
```

> And finally, my application/config/config.php:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://my.website.com';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

When i tested the above config on my local PC (running Ubuntu 14.04) it works just fine. However when i try to replicate the config on my server (running Ubuntu 14.04), somehow it does not work.

**Doing this:**

- http://my.website.com/ << Shows default Codeigniter welcome page
- http://my.website.com/controller_name/ << Shows :

  Not Found
  The requested URL /login was not found on this server.
  Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at my.website.com Port 80
- http://my.website.com/index.php/controller_name << shows the page, however URL to static files (i.e JS/CSS/images) are not properly fetched, since printing this:

  ```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/styles/material-design-icons.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/styles/font.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/styles/app.css" type="text/css" />
  ```

would append **index.php** when seen from source code inspector.

Am i missing something here? Can someone point me to the right direction?

Thanks.

EDIT #1
Below is my folder structure

[image: Dir Structure]

EDIT #2
I can confirm that mod_rewrite is enabled

[image: PHP Info]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31742035/codeigniter-routes-is-not-working/31742564#31742564

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, You mentioned lot of Stack links which related to  your question.

Change this settings

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

and add this in `.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```

> **Note:** Some time in localhost `index.php` will not removed.

and to **include your css/js/images**

> CSS:`<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/styles/material-design-icons.css" type="text/css" />`
>   JS : `<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/in/easing.js"></script>`
>   Img: `<img src="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/image/logo.jpg" alt=""/>`

So file structure would be

```
- application
- assets
  - style
     - material-design-icons.css
     - font.css
     - app.css
  - js
     - easing.js
  - image
     - logo.jpg
- index.php
- .htaccess(Post in my code)
```

**EDIT 01**

In `config/routes.php`

```
$route['default_controller'] = "";//give default controller name
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

Comment: I've tried your suggestion, how ever it still doesn't work. I try to call http://my.website.com/welcome and it still shows the same error message. However, invoking http://my.website.com/ shows default CI welcome message.

Comment: can I get online link ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85294/discussion-between-jeremy-r-irawan-and-abdulla).