# Routing configuration in Codeigniter 3

Tags: codeigniter, routes

This is my config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/mycms/';<br>
```

This is my routs.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = "Page";
$route['404_override'] = 'Page';
$route['article/(:num)/(:any)'] = 'article/index/$1/$2';
```

This is my Page.php
Now my main problem is I could not able to load 'http://localhost/mycms/'and seen '404 Page Not Found'

But If I browse following link then my site run well. localhost/mycms/index.php/Home-Page

Comment: use `page` instead of `Page` at `route.php` and make sure you have a file `Page.php` in controller folder and contains this line `class Page extends CI_controller`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Codeigniter URL rewrite to remove index.php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31853184/codeigniter-url-rewrite-to-remove-index-php)

Comment: Your question and problem has no relation.`404 Page Not Found` error happens for different reason. There are lots of answer on that.Search them

Answer (score 0):

In your root directory make a new file named as `.htaccess` with following code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

And in `application/config/config.php` set followings

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/mycms/';

$config['index_page'] = '';

$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply but I already do this, can you share any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is .htaccess Try this

in config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/mycms/';   //Your directory
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

create global .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|css|js|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]
```